# Uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus

[image: prove the function f(x)= Seq(Abs(x)) is uniformly continuous on its domain]
prove the function f(x)= Seq(Abs(x)) is uniformly continuous on its domain 
would someone please check my work. Thank you in advance .

Comment: People would be more willing to check your work if it was more readable: see [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: I have posted a picture for what I have done .

Answer (score 2):

Inside $[-1,1]$, it is u.c., since it's continuous on a compact set; outside,  $f'(x)$ is bounded, so it is also u.c.